# How to get value of a property?

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

I have a class that derives from `ExpressionVistor`, and I'm trying to parse an expression such as:

```
x => x.MyProperty != otherClass.OtherProperty;
```

I'm overriding VisitMember:

```
protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression m)
{
    if (m.Expression != null && m.Expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
    {
        var info = m.Member;

        return m;
    }
}
```

But how do I get the property value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get a value, you need the `Member` owner ([Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.memberexpression.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) property - *the containing object of the field or property*) to be either `null` (for static property/field), [ConstantExpression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.constantexpression(v=vs.110).aspx) or another `MemberAcccessExpression` (there are also other scenarios, but here we speak about simple `objA.propA.propB.propC` accessors). Which leads to a recursive helper method like this:

```
static bool TryGetValue(MemberExpression me, out object value)
{
    object source = null;
    if (me.Expression != null)
    {
        if (me.Expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Constant)
            source = ((ConstantExpression)me.Expression).Value;
        else if (me.Expression.NodeType != ExpressionType.MemberAccess
            || !TryGetValue((MemberExpression)me.Expression, out source))
        {
            value = null;
            return false;
        }
    }
    if (me.Member is PropertyInfo)
        value = ((PropertyInfo)me.Member).GetValue(source);
    else
        value = ((FieldInfo)me.Member).GetValue(source);
    return true;
}
```

so you can use it like this:

```
protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression m)
{
    object value;
    if (TryGetValue(m, out value))
    {
        // Use the value
    }

    return m;
}
```

Comment: But the  `NodeType` is `MemberAccess`.

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono Sorry, that was oversimplified, see if the update works for you.